# Making an application at ec2 accessible from the Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting

I have an ec2 free instance working as well as elastic IP, S3 and RDS. There is a folder with the sources of my application at `/home/ubuntu`. I run a built-in server inside this folder:

```
$ /home/ubuntu/my_app play run
```

It's running at port `9000` (at `my_app` folder). I have A and CNAME records at route53, but they point to the static html pages-stubs at s3, I did it for simplicity and, of course, they shouldn't point to the static pages.

I wonder, how do I make this running Play application visible from outside? I have no idea where in ec2 (or in route53) look for and set it. Obviously, I want it to be accessible as `my_custom_domain.com` (which I have) without specifying the port (`my_custom_domain.com:9000`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **To change your port from 9000 to 80** - If you work on ubuntu you can use [iptables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/)

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9000
   ```

   This will route all traffic coming from port 9000 to port 80
2. **To map your elastic IP to my_custom_domain.com** from the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html):

> Create a resource record set in your hosted zone. For Type, choose A –
>   Ipv4 address. For Value, specify the Elastic IP address for your
>   Amazon EC2 instance. For more information about creating a resource
>   record set, see Working with Resource Record Sets.

---

If you want to run several applications on the same server, each on a different port, but serve them each on a different DNS (for example: `http://www.my_domain.com` for port 8080, and `http://m.my_domain.com` for port 8081), you might want to use [`ELB`s](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/computebasics-linux/getting-started-create-lb.html) which can do port forwarding from port 80 to the application port.

With this configuration you can map each ELB as an [Alias](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html) on a `Route 53` Record Set.

Comment: how do I do the same without having to change it to 80 port?

Comment: Well, not. But I'm curious. What if I had 3 applications running of the different ports and I wanted them all to be accessible like this one?

Comment: Each on a different DNS?

Comment: Thanks. One more questions. My record A (name - example.com) points to my elastic IP address. What does CNAME have to point to (name - www.example)?

Comment: A CNAME does not point to an IP address, it points to another domain. http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/internet/difference-between-cname-and-a-record/

Comment: and what's the another domain in my case? www.example.com (to be more specific - "www") - the name of CNAME record, but what's the value?

Comment: I knew this, my gut told me.

Comment: When I run a server from the application folder on port 9000 and then try to access via IP, it doesn't work, meaning your solution of `sudo iptables -t....` doesn't work. Whereas, when I do the same supplying the IP address with port 9000, it does. Why is that?